# Unable to find controls inside DataTemplate in SilverLight5

Tags: c#, datatemplate, silverlight-5.0, itemscontrol

I am using `DataTemplate` where I've declared two `Buttons` and they are invisible by default. Now I want to make them `Visible` in code behind based on some condition but I am unable to find these controls.

Following is my code:

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="SynonymsItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Synonyms}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,0" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel x:Name="SynonymsStackPanel">
                <CheckBox x:Name="SynonymsChkBx" Content="{Binding Display}" Margin="10,0,0,0" />

                WANT TO FIND THESE TWO BUTTONS
                <Button x:Name="AddSynonymsBtn" Margin="525, 0, 0, 0" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Add Synonyms" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <Image Source="/Images/AddSynonyms.png" Height="24"/>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="CancelSynonymsBtn" Margin="600, 0, 0, 0" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Cancel Synonyms" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <Image Source="/Images/CancelSynonyms.png" Height="24"/>
                </Button>

            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

CODE-BEHIND:

I'm able to find ItemControl by doing this,

```
System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl itemControl = (from sp in selectedTreeViewItem.GetVisualDescendants().OfType<System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl>()
                                                    where sp.Name == "SynonymsItemsControl"
                                                    select sp).FirstOrDefault();
```

Now When I want to find buttons which are declared inside this `ItemsControl`->`DataTemplate`, it comes as `Null`

```
Button AddSynonymsBtn = (from btn in itemControl.GetVisualDescendants().OfType<Button>()
                         where btn.Name == "AddSynonymsBtn"
                         select btn).FirstOrDefault();
```

So I am wondering that do I need to find `ItemsControl` at all? if so, then why  am I unable to find these buttons?

I've also tried 
`var findControl = temControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);` but same result(`Null`).

Answer (score 0):

You can easly get controls from behind by using `Template.FindName(string Name);`

```
private Button _partSynonyms = null;

public MyControlTemplate{
   Loaded += (sender, e) => OnLoaded();
}

private void OnLoaded(){
   _partSynonyms = (Button)Template.FindName("PART_AddSynonymsBtn"); //You "should" use PART_ as a prefix in a Template
  if(_partSynonyms == null)
     //Button not found -> Log some error but you should not throw an exception
}
```